# Devise logs out current user on redirect during rspec feature test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am having an issue where I am writing an rspec feature test which authenticates to an application using devise and creates a record.

When hitting submit to create the record, on redirect, I am logged out of my session.

I can't seem to find anything odd in the logfile and I am able to reproduce this issue using both selenium-webdriver and chromedriver-helper.

I am wondering if anyone else has run into this issue and how you might have solved it.

My environment:

- rails 4.2.6
- devise 3.5.6
- selenium-webdriver 2.53.0
- chromedriver-helper 1.0.0
- rspec-rails 3.4.2
- capybara 2.7.0

spec/support/devise.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :view
end
```

spec/features/notes/create_note_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'note management' do
  scenario 'user can create a new note' do
    visit root_path
    click_link 'Sign In'
    fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'user_password', with: CONFIG[:test_user_password]
    click_button 'Log in'
    click_link 'Notes'
    click_link 'New Note'
    fill_in 'note_title', with: Faker::Lorem.word
    fill_in 'note_content', with: Faker::Lorem.paragraph
    click_button 'Create Note'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Note created'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable Warden Test Mode to make it all work.

Check this [wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara)

Comment: I did take a look at that wiki page. From what it reads, enabling Warden Test Mode is an option if I don't want to go through the login process for each feature test I create. I actually want to go through that process and Warden Test Mode stubs the user so that it bypasses the login process (If I understood correctly). Just incase, I did add the warden code to a support file and ran my specs again. I got the same issue. RSpec tells me the test failed with an output that I need to be logged in.

Comment: Variety of things that could have failed then. User name and password could be not set correctly, the root path could be access restricted as well and the redirect is not followed correctly, you could litter the code with some screenshot statements to see what is going on. Apart from that, it makes sense to bypass the login mechanism for feature specs and have one spec for the login separately, from a speed perspective. Your tests will take forever if you go through login every single spec.

Comment: Username and password are fine as I am able to login and get to the end of the test. Its just the form submission and redirect that is causing the session logout to happen. I tried this from a vanilla application with minimal code and I got the same result.  I have the authenticate_user! method in the application_controller.rb file since I want everything to prompt for a login but if I am already authenticated, then I should have access to the entire application without restriction. I tried running it through the browser and using pry at every step. Everything seems OK. Im truly baffled.